# What is a good way to phrase "in my experience" in a journal paper?

Tags: publications, writing-style

I want to say, "In our experience/as far as we know/etc., A only requires a few iterations to converge," without citing any relevant literature, particularly because I could not find any relevant literature on this topic.

What is an appropriate way to say that without being too "subjective"?

Comment: Avoid using it! No way to use that!

Comment: "Empirically" is often a fitting term.

Comment: "we found" or "in practice, XYZ avoided WVU"? Or even "we chose". Your paper describes the observations from your research. If you can defend not having qualified sources for some choices, surely you can state the choices.

Comment: In what field are you publishing?

Comment: I have used such phrase in multiple papers. For instance, the value H=5 is chosen based on prior modeling experience.

Comment: "We have observed that in our experiments algorithm A required < N iterations to converge".... Also make sure that you have the data to back up this claim in case someone asks (and even if no one asks!)

Comment: FerventHippo has a decent question worth answering. What field is it? The answer will depend on what the field is. Most science stuff, leave your experience out of it unless your confident its relevant (in which case there are good example rephrasings). For something like, say, the phenomenology of experience, experience might be really important however. The humanities of course aren't always doing the scientific method and have other approaches, so field does really matter here.

Comment: "Per standard practice" might work for some situations.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I would [challenge your framing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t) and ask why, exactly, you are caveating "your experience". I have no problem with "in our experience" as an expression. But what is it about *your* experience that you suspect might not replicate if others try it?

Try to locate what you have and haven't tested and be explicit about it. This sentence is reasonable:

> In our experience, sharks do not interrupt underwater basket weavers.

but this is much better:

> Over the past ten years we have often been approached by sharks while weaving baskets underwater with no adverse incidents. However, the local shark population is mostly composed of docile nurse sharks and sand sharks. As such, we would welcome further research into the safety of underwater basket weaving while in the vicinity of great white sharks, loan sharks, land sharks, or baby sharks (doo doo doo doo doo doo).

Comment: The first one is much better if you don't want to go into detail and if an excessively long explanation would be distracting

Comment: @toby544 - In my experience, mountain lions never interrupt dinner at home. But then, I've never seen a mountain lion at dinner, at home or in the woods. The second one has perhaps _necessary_ detail on underwater basketweaving shark safety precautions.

Comment: `or baby sharks (doo doo doo doo doo doo)` - I audibly laughed at this. I applaud the lengthy serious answer leading up to this joke. Well done.

Comment: @JonCuster OK. If several lines of details are necessary, then they are necessary, and if they are not, then they are not.

Comment: @3dbrows: I hope you didn't miss that final joke was immediately preceded by two more jokes, with both loan sharks and (depending on which of the related synonyms with different meanings you pick) land sharks belonging to the less waterborne types of shark ;)

Comment: [Land sharks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_Shark_(Saturday_Night_Live)) are particularly dangerous when one learns [underwater basket weaving](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_basket_weaving). (Although I wonder if these references give away my age ...)

Answer (score 24):

> as far as we know

Suggestion: "To the best of our knowledge, [...]".

> In our experience

Suggestion: "Based on our experiments, [...]".

Note that "experience" is much broader than "experiments". Therefore, in some contexts, "experience" can't be replaced with "experiments".

Comment: I wouldn't use "Based on our experiments", unless I have experiments in this paper that show this.

Comment: @terdon depends on the context. OP decides. I am just giving suggestions. "experience" is much broader than "experiments" indeed.

Comment: @J.Doe [Page limits](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/57071/452) may have chopped those extra experiments.

Answer (score 13):

In the following samples, let "IT" be "A only requires a few iterations to converge".

If IT is common knowledge:

> "As is well known, IT ..."

If IT is intuitive to a subject matter expert:

> "As is obvious, IT ..."

If IT was experimentally determined by you as part of your research and the experiment would be obvious to any expert in the field:

> "As we determined by simple experiment, IT ..."

If IT is an assumption based on your experience, but it may not be obvious to other experts in the field:

> "We assert that IT ..."

If you as an expert have a suspicion, but aren't strictly certain:

> "We believe it true that IT ..."

If you don't know:

> "We assume that IT ..."

Importantly, choose words that accurately reflect your knowledge about it. Don't try to bolster your argument by choosing words that connote stronger evidence than you actually have. That you're even asking the question suggests to me that you're on the right track!

You may also be interested in [Writing@CSU Writing Guide: Using the Toulmin Method](https://writing.colostate.edu/guides/pdfs/guide58.pdf). This approachable guide provides a systematic approach to examining and critiquing arguments based on evidence. I find it helpful after writing an article to "see it from the other side", breaking out of my author tunnel vision.

Comment: In general, I would recommend never saying something is obvious

Comment: “If Church said it’s obvious, then everybody saw it a half hour ago. If Weyl says it’s obvious, von Neumann can prove it. If Lefschetz says it’s obvious, it’s false.” - J. Barkley Rosser

Comment: I *despise* the words "obvious", "clearly", "trivial" and their ilk in mathematical writing.  I feel similarly about things like "it is well known...".  These are rhetorical crutches which don't actually add anything to the exposition, and have to potential to insult the reader.  If something is obvious, you don't have to tell the reader that it is obvious.  They'll know.  Compare "It is well-known that $2+2=4$, hence..." vs "Since $2+2=4$, ...".  Fewer words, *and* you aren't insulting your reader if they aren't up on the same literature as you.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Regarding your last example, I think the opposite way. IMO (unless you're referring to a fact established earlier in the paper) "Since [fact],... " is no better than "Obviously [fact], so... "; both versions suggest, either explicitly or implicitly, that the reader should be able to see why the fact is true. "It is well known that [fact], so..." reassures the reader that it is not "obvious".

Answer (score 3):

I have no problems with "in my experience". Particularly, I don't see why it improves anything regarding objectivity to use words that "sound more objective" to say the same thing. Either you have convincing reasons or evidence that could be explained (then explain them in detail), or it's just your experience, and then I don't see any reason not to be honest about it.